# Using glue_data() in a function works with some column names and not others

Tags: r, function, r-glue

I'm working on a function that takes a dataframe and user-specified columns as inputs and uses glue_data() to output some nicely formatted text.

Whether or not a variable works seems to be the luck of the draw, but is consistent from attempt to attempt. e.g. with mtcars, mpg always works, and hp never does:

```
library(glue)
data <- head(mtcars)

print_messages <- function(x=NULL, att1=NULL, att2=NULL) {
  
  # This if-else seems to be the problem
  if(is.null(att1)) {
    att1_glue <- ""
  } else {
    att1_glue <- paste0("{", deparse(substitute(att1)),"}")
  }
  
  if(is.null(att2)) {
    att2_glue <- ""
  } else {
    att2_glue <- paste0("{", deparse(substitute(att2)),"}")
  }
  
  pattern <-   paste("", att1_glue,"", att2_glue)        
  
  glue_data(x, pattern)
  
}

print_messages(data, att1=mpg, att2=NULL) 

# 21  
# 21  
# 22.8  
# 21.4  
# 18.7  
# 18.1  

print_messages(data, att1=mpg, att2=hp)
#> Error in print_messages(data, att1 = mpg, att2 = hp): object 'hp' not found
```

This is not a function of which variable goes in `att1` vs `att2`

I have figured out that the if-else is the problem, but don't know how to fix it. It was inserted because I can't just have a null argument -- this makes `glue_data()` return a 0-character string:

```
print_messages <- function(x=NULL,att1=NULL, att2=NULL) {
  
  att1_glue <- paste0("{", deparse(substitute(att1)),"}")
  att2_glue <- paste0("{", deparse(substitute(att2)),"}")
  
  pattern <-   paste("",att1_glue,"", att2_glue)        
  
  glue_data(x, pattern)
  
}


print_messages(data, att1=mpg, att2=hp )
# 21  110
# 21  110
# 22.8  93
# 21.4  110
# 18.7  175
# 18.1  105

print_messages(data, att1=hp, att2=NULL )
```

I have tried other approaches to using the argument from the function in `glue_data()`, like from [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65083998) But the central issue seems to be with the if-else.

I'm wondering what's going on there? Even if there is a way to fix this on the `glue` side, I'd be interested in why the parsing works with some columns and not others!

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evaluation of non-existing objects will throw an error.

```
f <- function(x = NULL) if(is.null(x)) cat("hi") else cat("bye")
f(mpg) # error
f("mpg")
#> bye
f()
#> hi
```

The first function should throw an error, do you perhaps have an object called mpg in your environment? In that case lexical scoping will find it, and yield `is.null(mpg)` as `FALSE`.

An alternative is to use dots `...`, and using the *vectorized* nature of `paste`, avoiding the need for pre-filled arguments with `NULL`.

```
print_messages <- function(data, ...){
  expr = paste0("{", 
                vapply(substitute(...()), deparse, "")
                , "}", collapse = " ")
  glue_data(data, expr)
}
```